# O Programa não avança

Tags: python

Espero que estejam bem! Tenho tentado fazer um sistema que pede o cadastro e que após a confirmação do mesmo, caminha para a tela de login. Logo após efetuar o mesmo, aparecerá novas opções. A questão é: EU NÃO CONSIGO SAIR DESSA PARTE! Segue abaixo o código:

```
#coding: utf8
#Criado por: Lorran Rocha dos Santos


#--------------BOAS VINDAS--------------#
print("Bem-Vindo!")
welcome = input("Você já tem uma conta? S/N  ")

#--------------VERIFICAR ESCOLHA--------------#
def cadastro(welcome, username, email, cpf, endereco,celular,password,password1):
    if welcome == "n" or "N":
        while True:
            username  = input("Digite um Nome de Usuario:")
            email = input("Digite seu email:")
            cpf = input("Digite seu CPF:")
            endereco = input("Digite seu endereço completo:")
            celular = input("Digite seu numero de celular:")
            password  = input("Digite uma Senha:")
            password1 = input("Confirme sua Senha:")
            if password == password1:
                file = open(username+".txt", "w")
                file.write(username+":"+password)
                file.close()
                welcome = "s"
                break
            print("As senhas não batem!")

def login():

        if welcome == "s" or "S":
            while True:
                login1 = input("Login:")
                login2 = input("Senha:")
                file = open(login1+".txt", "r")
                data   = file.readline()
                file.close()
                if data == login1+":"+login2:
                    print("Bem-Vindo!")
                    break
                print("Usuário ou Senha incorretos.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens muitos erros neste excerto de código.

**Primeiro erro:** Não estás a chamar a função `cadastro` e `login` em nenhum lado do teu script, apenas os inicializaste.

Como corrigir:

```
while True:
    welcome = input("Você já tem uma conta? S/N  ")
    if not (welcome == 's' or welcome == 'S' or welcome == 'n' or welcome == 'N'): #Se não for nenhuma desta opções
        break
    if welcome == 's' or welcome == 'S':
        #Call login function
    else:
        #Call cadastro function
```

**Segundo erro:** A tua função `cadastro` não precisa de nenhum parâmetro. As variáveis que tu tens como parâmetros, vais obtê-las dentro da função.

**Terceiro erro:** Na função `cadastro`, mesmo que as password coincidam, tu vais sempre imprimir 'As senhas não batem bem'. O mesmo acontece na função login

Como corrigir:

```
if password == password1:
    #Do what you have to do
else:
    print('As senhas não batem!')

#Tens de fazer o mesmo na função de login
```

**Quarto erro:** Não estás a ler bem o ficheiro. Apenas estás a ler uma linha. O que acontece se tiveres registrado duas ou mais contas?

Ps: Tens mais erros possíveis de serem melhorados, vou deixar tu descobrires por ti, estarei aqui para ajudar a resolver

Comment: Mas como eu chamaria a função?

Comment: apenas `login()`
Como a função `login` não tem parãmetros, basta chamar com dois parêntesis curvos sem nada no meio.

Quando uma função tem parâmetros, aí sim tem que colocar:
`funcao(param1, param2)`

Comment: Você me salvou! Obrigado!

Comment: De nada amigo, se precisares de mais ajuda, avisa! Dê upvote se ajudou, aceite a resposta se suas dúvidas estão esclarecidas!

Comment: Aqui só fica falando que o "break" está fora do loop. Eu tento diversos tipos de endentação e nada...

Comment: Posta o teu código atual

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108020/discussion-between-joao-castilho-and-lorran-rocha).